# “Text from your phone asking me to meet.” Why is it "asking"?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, gerunds, ing

In the movie *Taken 3* (2015), one character is looking at a text message on a mobile phone, and he says to another character:

> Text from your phone asking mom to meet you at the rancho Berrego the night she died. Someone used your phone.

Why is the verb *asking* in this sentence in the *-ing* form?

If the verb, *ask*, is in the continuous tense, why is there no *“to be”*?
And why should we use present continuous here, and not the simple past?

Comment: You should probably be asking this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where I commend [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/38715/126) to *Should we always use “verb+ ing” structure after the verb “start”?* In essence, people would tend to avoid *Text **to** ask me **to** meet* because of the "horror aequi" principle. Your particular example might be stretching things a bit - I suspect not everyone would accept that the gerund "works" there, but I have no problem with *I'm going to ring her tomorrow asking for a date* (which is syntactically equivalent).

Comment: @Majid, please clarify context. Is this a imperative from someone, telling you to "Text from your phone asking me to meet"?  Or was it more like a simple statement: "I got a text from your phone asking me to meet"?

Comment: What precisely is the context? Could you say where you read this? The more context and information you give, the more likely you will receive a helpful answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Johnny strings , @ Mari-Lou A ,I saw that in "taken 3 " the movie....it was a text massage...

Comment: So, what happened afterwards? Did the person go and  meet someone or did they call/text someone?

Comment: @Majid No, it wasn't. Having looked at the script, it is clear what is going on: there's a text on a phone that someone is looking at. Referring to that text, he says to someone else: “Text from your phone asking mom to meet you at the rancho Berrego the night she died. Someone used your phone.” _Text_ here is indeed a noun, and the sentence includes an unspoken “there is a” or “this is a” at the start.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet ...yes exactly... So you mean that it's simple present...???...if yes , why" there is a " is omitted...???

Comment: Because it’s colloquial. Just like if you’re making something to eat and there’s a friend with you, you don’t have to say “Do you want a sandwich as well?”—you can get the same message through just by saying “Sandwich?”. From the context, it’s clear that he’s talking about the text message that he’s looking and pointing at, so he doesn’t have to say “this is a text message…”. The participle _asking_ has the function described in James’ answer.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet thanks a lot....I somehow got it... But some questions.... 1. Is it different if we use present participle or past participle...can we say "text from your phone asked...."??

Comment: No, you cannot use the past participle here. A participle phrase with a present participle is _active_, while a participle phrase with a past participle is _passive_. A passive sentence here would make no sense (the text message had not been asked anything) and would also be ungrammatical (“There is a text message from your phone, which was asked mom to meet you” is complete gibberish—a passive verb cannot have a direct object).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, fantastic explanation.. I saw a sentence in yahoo news today....is this one exactly like the previous..." Arab star attacked by a monkey leaving her shocked " I mean about " leaving"

Comment: That’s an awful lot of participle phrases in one clause—and quite confusing punctuation, too. It’s a headline, so even matrix (=main) verbs are often left out. The intended meaning is, “An Arab star [was] attacked by a monkey, leaving [= which has left] her shocked”; but without the comma before _leaving_, what it actually says is, “An Arab star [who was] attacked by a monkey [who was] leaving her [is] shocked”. That is, the star was attacked by a leaving monkey, and she is shocked. But that’s nonsense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28834/discussion-between-majid-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Comment: Is this sentence correct "I like student asking a lot of questions"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, "asking me to meet", is a participle phrase, which describes the text.

Participle phrases are discussed at grammar monster:
http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm

The phrase quoted may not be complete sentence, it could be a noun phrase. A sentence could be "I received a text from your phone asking me to meet". or if "Text" is considered to be an imperative, it makes a complete but rather uncomfortably (to me) phrased sentence.

Comment: ... and a search for 'participle phrase' here gives 387 results. This might just be a duplicate.

Comment: The "main verb" is ***text*** - it's an ordinary imperative construction, where the implied subject ***you*** is omitted. So it's a "complete sentence" by normal definitions. You might find it easier to imagine likely contexts if it was preceded by, say, *When you're ready to talk about it, just **text from your phone**...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I read *text* as being synonymous with "message" The sentence being: "There's **a text** on your phone which is asking me to meet up with (somebody)" Let's pretend we know their name and say "...asking me to meet [up with] Tom"

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Absent evidence to the contrary, we should assume OP understands the difference between a *sentence* and a *noun phrase*, so if he calls his text a sentence, we should assume that's how it's *intended* to be parsed. Incidentally, even if we substitute *message* for *text*, that could still be an imperative verb usage - *Here's my mobile phone number. **Message** me when you arrive at the station, and I'll come and pick you up*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and why would we assume that the OP understands the difference between a sentence and a noun phrase? How many native speakers would even *know* what a noun phrase is? "*There is a message/text* **from** *your mobile*" sounds perfectly plausible to me, and the one I interpreted it as meaning. Did you read the question before it was edited by me? The OP wrote: *Why the verb in this sentence is in ing form??* The OP does not know how to write a question in English.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Why should we assume anyone knows anything? Well, apart from anything else, it's *polite* (here on ELU, read *welcoming*). Your assumption that OP actually intends his example to be understood as a "cut-down" version of ***There is** [a text message...]* implies an unjustified slur on his competence in English. Whilst I don't deny that this is *feasible*, why go out of your way to think the worst of new users here? Particularly when your "deviant" interpretation has no idiomatic currency (not even in colloquial, lazy/uneducated, or dialectal usage, so far as I'm aware).

Comment: @FumbleFingers    OK, "there's a message on your phone" is the idiomatic expression, I admit, but you cannot rule out the possibility of *text* being a noun in the OP's example. The text is *coming from* your phone, is a possible interpretation. The OP's example is an example of a sort of telegraphic English. There is nothing "willfully" about me misinterpreting the OP's question. I'm saying there are TWO possible readings.

Comment: ...I did point out in my initial comment that this OP might feel more at home (and get better answers) on ELL. *And* I pointed out that the example is at least slightly unusual. But the fact that both you and James here have (willfully or ignorantly) "misinterpreted" the example suggests there's a more serious problem relating to how nns are treated on ELU. If there's any reasonable justification for assuming an OP does in fact understand any peripheral issues arising within the context of his post, I think that's the line we should take by default.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the possiblity of "Text" being the verb. Its possible. As a verb, "text" is most often used with a direct object ("text me"), and adding "from your phone" is slightly peculiar (to me). I'll edit my answer. The actual answer (asking is a present participle) I think is correct.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, having looked up the quote, Mari-Lou and James (and myself) interpreted the sentence correctly. It's someone pointing to a mobile phone with a text on it, explaining to someone else: “Text from your phone asking mom to meet you at the rancho Berrego the night she died. Someone used your phone.” The fact that it was misquoted in the question doesn't help, of course; but whether this, which is used as a standalone sentence, syntactically qualifies as one or not is not something we can expect especially new users to know. To most people, native or no, it's a sentence.

Comment: @Janus: Ho hum. Well, James has edited his answer here so it's no longer relevant. Whether it's used as an imperative, or a "verbless diminished utterance" (i.e. - a noun phrase) in the original context has no bearing on the choice between infinitive and gerund for ***ask***. And I *still* think this question would be a better fit on ELL.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A is correct which is  obvious from the context.  In *Taken 3* they are looking at their mom's phone when they say the quote. What's missing is not a "you" to make it an imperative. The correct interpretation is "[there is a] text from your phone asking mom to meet."